# Bucket sort for gaussian / standard distribution

Tags: sorting, statistics

I know [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80913/bucket-sort-with-gaussian-distribution). But I still have no idea to adapt the bucket sort algorithm to handle input with a gaussian / normal distribution. Can someone provide me a Pseudocode / Python code for that? So far I tried the following, but sadly it does not work, and I don't understand why.

```
def bucket_sort(numbers):
    mean = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
    variance = sum((x - mean) ** 2 for x in numbers) / len(numbers)
    std_deviation = math.sqrt(variance)

    num_buckets = int( math.sqrt(len(numbers)) )
    buckets = [[] for _ in range(num_buckets)]

    for num in numbers:
        index = int( ( (num - mean) / std_deviation) * num_buckets)
        buckets[index].append(num)

    for bucket in buckets:
        bucket.sort()

    sorted_numbers = [num for bucket in buckets for num in bucket]

    return sorted_numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ denote the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) for your distribution.  Suppose you want $N$ buckets.  Then use the following buckets:

$$(F^{-1}(0),F^{-1}(1/N)],(F^{-1}(1/N),F^{-1}(2/N)],\dots,(F^{-1}((N-1)/N),F^{-1}(1)].$$

This ensures that about $1/N$ of the samples fall into each bucket.  Then, use bucket sort with these buckets.

To compute which bucket a value $x$ falls into, it suffices to compute the cdf for $x$.  In particular, $x$ goes into bin number $\lfloor F(x) N \rfloor$.

This works for any distribution, assuming the distribution is known and you can compute the cdf.

Comment: I really try to understand that, but I don't. First I have no idea how to compute/approximate that. Second: If I only compute the boundaries of the buckets, and not the indices, I have to loop over the element to find the correct bucket. I could improve this using binary search, but I still mess up the time complexity of bucket sort... Can you help me further, maybe provide a codeline for calculating the index, assuming the buckets have an index 0,1,...,b?

Comment: The *inverse* $\text{cdf}$ gives the bounds of the intervals. But to get the bucket where a given value goes, you need the *direct* $\text{cdf}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, oh, right!  Thank you.  Answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally understand, what is happening. The input is distributed with a normal distribution. This leads us to a normal probability distribution function PDF for the probability of the elements. We can describe the distribution using the mean µ and derivative $\sigma$:

$$
µ = \frac{\sum_{n \in N} n}{| N |}  \quad \sigma = \sqrt{\frac{ \sum_{n \in N} (n - µ )^2 }{| N |}}
$$

The cumulative distribution function CDF is the integral over the PDF and creates a uniform random distributed output for the elements in the initial distribution. The reason for the uniformity is based on a phenomena called probability integral transform. In the case of normal distribution the CDF is closely related to the errorfunction, BUT NOT exactly the error function. A mistake that took me way too long to realise. The CDF is as follows:

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} * (1 + erf(\frac{x - µ}{\sigma \sqrt 2}))
$$

where $erf$ refers to the error function. Last but not least we want buckets and because we have an integral over probability, we only have values between 0 and 1. We can simply rescale using the number of buckets and we are done. This way, we can build a bucket sort for normal/gaussian distribution which is still in $O(n)$. My result:

```
import math
import scipy.stats

def bucket_sort(numbers, mean, deviation):
    # Just recompute here to see what happens
    mean = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
    variance = sum((x - mean) ** 2 for x in numbers) / len(numbers)
    deviation = math.sqrt(variance)

    num_buckets = int( math.sqrt(len(numbers)) ) 
    buckets = [[] for _ in range(num_buckets)]

    for num in numbers:
        # index = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(num, mean, deviation)
        tmp = (num - mean)/(deviation*math.sqrt(2))
        index = 0.5 *(1+math.erf(tmp))
        index = int(index * num_buckets)

        # Append rescaled value to bucket
        buckets[index].append(num)

    for bucket in buckets:
        bucket.sort()

    sorted_numbers = [num for bucket in buckets for num in bucket]

    return sorted_numbers

# example call
mean = 50
std = 20
input = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(50,20,100)
input = [int(i) for i in input]
print(bucket_sort(input,mean, std))
```

I am not quite sure whether I should thank Yves Daoust or not :D At least he tried to help me, which I appreciate a lot, but I am sorry, your input wasn't quite helpful. What helped me a lot, was [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161635/why-is-the-cdf-of-a-sample-uniformly-distributed) post.